# Google calender localization

Tags: json, google-api, localization, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to use google holiday calender API to fetch event list for different countries in there locale language using the below url, but still I'm getting event list in default language english.

```
url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/malaysia__mu@holiday.calendar.google.com/events?key=mykey&
timeMin=2018-03-18T00:00:00Z&timeMax=2018-12-01T00:00:00Z&maxResults=24&orderBy=startTime&singleEvents=true
```

Response:

```
[{"event": "Easter Sunday", "date_start": "2018-04-01", "date_end": "2018-04-02"}, {"event": "Isra and Mi'raj", "date_start": "2018-04-13", "date_end": "2018-04-14"}, {"event": "Labour Day", "date_start": "2018-05-01", "date_end": "2018-05-02"}, {"event": "Ramadan begins", "date_start": "2018-05-16", "date_end": "2018-05-17"}, {"event": "Wesak Day", "date_start": "2018-05-29", "date_end": "2018-05-30"}, {"event": "Harvest Festival", "date_start": "2018-05-30", "date_end": "2018-05-31"}, {"event": "Harvest Festival Day 2", "date_start": "2018-05-31", "date_end": "2018-06-01"}, {"event": "Hari Raya Puasa Day 1", "date_start": "2018-06-15", "date_end": "2018-06-16"}, {"event": "Hari Raya Puasa Day 2", "date_start": "2018-06-16", "date_end": "2018-06-17"}, {"event": "Georgetown World Heritage City Day", "date_start": "2018-07-07", "date_end": "2018-07-08"}, {"event": "Penang Governor's Birthday", "date_start": "2018-07-14", "date_end": "2018-07-15"}, {"event": "Hari Raya Haji", "date_start": "2018-08-22", "date_end": "2018-08-23"}, {"event": "Malaysia's National Day", "date_start": "2018-08-31", "date_end": "2018-09-01"}, {"event": "The Yang di-Pertuan Agong's Birthday", "date_start": "2018-09-08", "date_end": "2018-09-09"}, {"event": "Muharram/New Year", "date_start": "2018-09-11", "date_end": "2018-09-12"}, {"event": "Malaysia Day", "date_start": "2018-09-16", "date_end": "2018-09-17"}]
```

event is not coming in malay language
can someone will give lead on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google calendar returns the data in the language it has which is most often English.  It has no support for returning data in any other language.

It will be up to you to translate it to your chosen language when the data is returned to you.

Comment: Is it possible to customise the public holidays calender response because the above API is giving the response in which some event are not holidays and some event's date is mention wrong so is it possible to customise it, if yes, how?

Comment: These are calendar created by and controlled by Google you don't have control over that. You may want to make your own